# How to stop mosquitos from living in the window curtains and drapes

Tags: windows, interior, screens, curtain-rail, mosquitoes

I'm observing that **mosquitoes** are living in the **window curtains and drapes** during **daytime** like a indoor **safe haven** and it starts the blood sucking spree when sun sets.

I have seen people using the electric racket for killing mosquitos during daytime.

I'm planning to buy some window curtains and drapes for my home.

What are the things I should be careful about while buying and installing window curtains and drapes for my home so I can avoid or prevent this mosquito menace.

Comment: Question seems vague and contradictory.

Comment: @RobertChapin - I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that you are writing from India. Your National Center for Vector Borne Diseases Control publishes [instructions](https://ncvbdc.mohfw.gov.in/WriteReadData/l892s/Treatment%20and%20Use%20of%20Insecticide-final-18-04-03.doc) (Word doc) for treating mosquito nets with a specific insecticide mix that they say is safe for use around pregnant women and children. It contains Deltamethrin and Cyfluthrin.

You could treat mosquito nets as directed and hang them with your curtains, or it may be possible to treat the curtains themselves. The insecticide encourages the mosquitos to go somewhere else, but if they stay, they die.

Note that the published instructions say that you can wash the nets three times while still retaining effectiveness, and the treatment should be performed twice per year.

Answer (score 2):

Treat them with  [permethrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permethrin), which is an insecticide (that remains on cloth and kills insects on contact for a long time after treatment.) On something only rarely laundered such as curtains, it should remain effective for quite some time, but occasional retreatment when effectiveness fades would be expected.

Comment: Sounds a lot safer than most drug ads adverse/side effects(death, suicide, stoke).